# Need help figuring out repeatable equals and addition operator events

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I am building a UWP calculator app using the MVVM pattern and I have just about everything figured out except how to get the equals button to calculate repeatedly and have my operator buttons work correctly. I can do one or the other, but I can't figure out how to do both. The code below works for a repeatable equals button, but the plus operator will yield the wrong answer when adding multiple values.

If I take out the second switch statement and change the variables back to using one Output variable then I can get the plus operator to work, but the equals button will fail when it repeats.

I am sure it is just a matter of adding a nested if statement or the addition of a bool somewhere, but I'm stumped! Please help. I've removed the non essential buttons and operators. Any other helpful suggestions on my code would be appreciated too.
Thank you!

```
public class ComputareViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Private Fields
    private double resultNumber = 0;
    private double xResultNumber;
    private double yResultNumber;
    private string _outputValue = "0";

    bool isOperationPerformed = false;
    bool EqualsRepeated = false;


    public ComputareViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string OutputValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _outputValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _outputValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutputValue");
        }
    }

    public void OnNumberBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((_outputValue) == "0" || (isOperationPerformed))
            _outputValue = "";

        isOperationPerformed = false;
        Button numberBtnClick = (Button)sender;

        if ((string)numberBtnClick.Content == ".")
        {
            if (!_outputValue.Contains("."))
            {
                    OutputValue = OutputValue + numberBtnClick.Content;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                OutputValue = OutputValue + numberBtnClick.Content;
        }
    }

    public void OnOperatorBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        Button operatorBtnClick = (Button)sender;

        if(isOperationPerformed == false)
        {
            if (xResultNumber != 0)
            {
                OnEqualsBtnClick(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
                operationPerformed = (string)operatorBtnClick.Content;
                isOperationPerformed = true;
                EqualsRepeated = false;
            }
            else
            {
                operationPerformed = (string)operatorBtnClick.Content;
                xResultNumber = Double.Parse(OutputValue);
                isOperationPerformed = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Do nothing.
        }
    }

    public void OnEqualsBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (EqualsRepeated == false)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(OutputValue, out yResultNumber))
                switch (operationPerformed)
                {
                    case "+":
                        {
                            OutputValue = (xResultNumber + yResultNumber).ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            isOperationPerformed = true;
            EqualsRepeated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // If equals has already been clicked
            if (EqualsRepeated == true)
                if (double.TryParse(OutputValue, out xResultNumber))
                    switch (operationPerformed)
                    {
                        case "+":
                            {
                                OutputValue = (xResultNumber + yResultNumber).ToString();
                                break;
                            }
                    }
        }
        isOperationPerformed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have button click events in your view model?

Comment: He can do that with x:Bind :)

Comment: RoutedEventArgs  are a new feature with UWP X:Bind. I found them simpler then implementing Commads, which I've done for the Output value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logical problems in your code. First, after `OnEqualsBtnClick` is called, `isOperationPerformed` is true, if you want to call the `OnOperatorBtnClick`, it will always go to the `else` part and do nothing. Second, if you repeat click euqal button, `xResultNumber` is not 0, if you want to call `OnOperatorBtnClick`, it will then call the `OnEqualsBtnClick`, but `EqualsRepeated` is true now, so you should change `EqualsRepeated` to `false`. At last, `xResultNumber` is the value of last calculation, you should set it to `0` in `OnEqualsBtnClick` method.

So you can change your code like this:

```
public void OnOperatorBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Button operatorBtnClick = (Button)sender;
    EqualsRepeated = false;
    if (isOperationPerformed == false)
    {
        if (xResultNumber != 0)
        {
            OnEqualsBtnClick(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            operationPerformed = (string)operatorBtnClick.Content;
            isOperationPerformed = true;
            EqualsRepeated = false;
        }
        else
        {
            operationPerformed = (string)operatorBtnClick.Content;
            xResultNumber = Double.Parse(OutputValue);
            isOperationPerformed = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Do nothing. 
    }
}

public void OnEqualsBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    if (EqualsRepeated == false)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(OutputValue, out yResultNumber))
            switch (operationPerformed)
            {
                case "+":
                    {
                        OutputValue = (xResultNumber + yResultNumber).ToString();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        isOperationPerformed = true;
        EqualsRepeated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // If equals has already been clicked
        if (EqualsRepeated == true)
            if (double.TryParse(OutputValue, out xResultNumber))
                switch (operationPerformed)
                {
                    case "+":
                        {
                            OutputValue = (xResultNumber + yResultNumber).ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                }
    }
    isOperationPerformed = false;
    xResultNumber = 0;
}
```